# implement copy constructor c++ Polynomial and Rational

Tags: c++

I need some help to understand how to implement the constructor in the Rational class.
I try to send the numerator(p1) and denominator(p2) by reference to the rational class however it start both of them to "0" and not copy them.

the idea is to create rational that contain two Polynomial (numerator and denominator) and print them.

I didn't add all the code just what I think is relevant.

```
class Polynomial
{
private:
double *varibles;
static int degree;

public:
Polynomial(double * var = NULL, static int deg = NULL);  
Polynomial(static int deg );
 };



class Rational
{
private:
Polynomial  numerator;
Polynomial  denominator;

public:
Rational(const Polynomial&  p1   , const Polynomial & p2 );
```

cpp file

```
Rational::Rational(const  Polynomial& p1  , const Polynomial & p2 ) 
{
this->numerator =  p1;
this->denominator = p2;
}







Polynomial::Polynomial(double * var, static int deg) { 
if (deg < (sizeof(var) / sizeof(double)))
    var = (double*)realloc(var, deg * sizeof(double));
this -> degree = deg;
this -> varibles = var;

}
Polynomial::Polynomial(static int deg) {
this->degree = deg;
this->varibles = (double*)calloc(deg, sizeof(double));
}


void Polynomial::setCoeff(int index, double num) {
if (!this->degree) 
    Polynomial(index);

this->varibles[index] = num;
}



void Polynomial::SetPolynomial(Polynomial& p) {
int size = p.degree;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << "Enter Number for X^ " << i+1 << "  varibles" << endl;
    cin >> p.varibles[i];
}

}

double Polynomial::getDegree(bool what) const {
if (what == false)
    return this->degree;
else
    return 0;
}

 double Polynomial::getCoeff(int index) const {
return this->varibles[index];
 }

int Polynomial::getMaxDegree() {
return degree;
}



void Polynomial::print() {
int size = this->degree ; // -1 ? 
int i;
if (!this->degree)
    cout << "Polynomial = 0";
else {
    while (this->varibles[size] == 0)
        size--;

    if (size < 1 && this->varibles[0] == 0) {
        cout << "Polynomial = 0";

    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                cout << this->varibles[i] << "+";
            else
                cout  << this->varibles[i] << "X^" << i << "+";

        }


        cout  << this->varibles[i] << "X^" << i ;
    }
}
cout << endl;


}
```

main / test

```
void testRational() {
Rational r1;
r1.print();
double c[] = { 0,2,2,3,4,5 };
Polynomial p1(c, 5);
p1.print();
c[0] = 1.2; 
Polynomial p2(c, 3);
Rational r2(p1, p2);
cout << "test8" << endl;
r2.print();
```

Comment: Note: you appear to have `Polynomial` with a pointer to `double` to allocate an array during construction. May I suggest a `std::vector` instead? Also, use an initializer list in `Rational`'s constructor rather than assignments to `list->...`.

Comment: I would replace your raw arrays with `std::vector<double>`. Also you are misusing the `static` keyword.

Comment: @Chris I shouldn't use std::vector

Comment: You need a copy constructor and assignment operator in `Polynomial`. You should also read about the constructor's initializer list in your favourite C++ book. If your `Polynomial` is correct, `Rational` shouldn't need to do anything complicated at all.

Comment: Note that `degree` is shared among all polynomials, and you can't use it to tell the degree of one of them. Also, you can't specify `static` on parameters, so that's not even similar to your real code.

Comment: @YoavLavie if you aren't allowed to use `std::vector`, write a `homework::vector` *once* and use it wherever. The *idomatic* way to write copy constructors is to [*not* write them if you possibly can](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).

Comment: @YoavLavie, if this is homework, and there are conditions on libraries you can use, you should state as much in your question.

Comment: @Chris there is another way to do it without using vector ?

Comment: Of course. `std:: vector` just makes things easier and cleaner.